# Asterisk - abort scheduled auto dial - call file spool

Tags: file, asterisk, phone-call, abort

Is there any way to flush pbx_spools's cache?
pbx_spool.so didn't support reload by CLI too.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >/tmp/wakeup.call <<EOF
Channel: SIP/telefon
CallerID: "Weckruf" <9999>
MaxRetries: 3
WaitTime: 60
Context: wecker
Extension: s
Priority: 1
EOF
touch -d "7 hours" /tmp/wakeup.call

# At this point Asterisk learns his task
mv /tmp/wakeup.call /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/

# for demonstration I decided to not want to be waken later
sleep 10 && rm /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/wakeup.call
```

Finally Asterisk does ring 7 hours later...

I'd expect, if I delete the .call-file manually from /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/ before it should be dialed that Asterisk didn't place the call anymore. But it does.

Comment: Deleting the file should prevent the call. What does the Asterisk console say?

Comment: The console does say nothing even with debug and verbosity 1000

Comment: I find it unlikely that Asterisk can make a call without putting anything out to the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this behavior is the use of unique filenames.

Asterisk reads in the callfile at the point of creation and only checks at the time of execution if a file with that identical name is still present. Regardless of what's in there.

Either Asterisk didn't mention the removal of the file in between.
The filename with its contents is still hammered in the stack and even newly created files with the same filename are ignored. Only the presence of a file with that name at the time of execution makes asterisk triggering the initial callfile contents.

Comment: Good to know; do you have a source where you found this information, or just trial and error?

Comment: Read this too late. Sry. This behavior was tested by try&error and later on verified in the source code of pbx_spool.c. I have not checked if it still applies today. I found this to be undocumented.